# Fonts app hangs after being opened

Tags: fonts, steam, crash

I'm a new Ubuntu user, so I tried to use the “Try” option via the installer get a feel of how it would run on my system. I found one problem in particular where after installing the Steam app none of fonts were readable, and on further inspection, this was because the Arial font wasn’t installed, so I installed it to test. As a result I found that when opening the fonts app, it simply hangs there until I force quit. On one occasion it actually crashed the whole OS and I had to hard reboot to try again.

I’m wondering if this problem is just because I haven’t actually installed it to a proper drive yet. I’m hesitant to fully install the OS if this problem occurs so any advice or knowledge on this would be very helpful. Thanks.

Things I’ve tried:

1. Using the drive in a different PC
2. Using a different USB drive
3. Re-downloading the IOS
4. Using a different installer (Rufus, Linux live USB)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it hangs preparing font previews, maybe some permissions issue.

Open a terminal and start with `sudo gnome-font-viewer`. Let it process and quit. You can open normally afterwards (with some random crash in-between), and it works.

Comment: This solved it for me. Had to run it once as a sudoer.

Comment: Even in 22.01 gnome-font-viewer is not only still buggy, its features are desperately poor.  Try `apt install font-manager` to appreciate what a decently written app can (should) do.

Comment: @Déjàvu font-manager only shows 2 fonts.  It doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same problem by installing the font-manager application.

Comment: This is happening to me in Ubuntu 22.04 and this also solves it nicely, much better app for fonts actually.

Answer (score 0):

apparently it's a confirm bug in Ubuntu distribution.

Font app freezes also in "proper" installation.

more info here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-font-viewer/+bug/1848942